# TVHeadEnd on Pi saying "No input detected"

Tags: input, dmesg, raspberrypi

This is my first time posting on here. I had a ubuntu 12.04.3LTS server running TVHeadEnd, with a RPi as the frontend. Everything was working fine, i then went and brought myself a little Dell Poweredge 1950. I have created a VM of the working server that was running TVHeadEnd, added the USB to the config settings, it gets everything, all the MUX's are there, perfect signal and quality. So i go to set the Pi up, reset all the DVB and PVR databases and its coming up with "TVHeadEnd HTSP: No input detected".

So after a while of looking around in the server, i came to the Dmesg log, i have added just the end part (everything from the start of the DVB config):

```
[   13.531334] dvb-usb: found a 'Hauppauge Nova-TD Stick (52009)' in cold state, will try to load a firmware
[   13.548551] dvb-usb: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw'
[   13.821865] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   14.646128] init: failsafe main process (584) killed by TERM signal
[   15.130773] type=1400 audit(1391719987.659:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=753 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.131423] type=1400 audit(1391719987.663:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=753 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.131645] type=1400 audit(1391719987.663:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=753 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.149650] type=1400 audit(1391719987.679:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=755 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.490533] dib0700: firmware started successfully.
[   18.993964] dvb-usb: found a 'Hauppauge Nova-TD Stick (52009)' in warm state.
[   18.994473] dvb-usb: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer.
[   18.995615] DVB: registering new adapter (Hauppauge Nova-TD Stick (52009))
[   19.939357] usb 1-1: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (DiBcom 7000PC)...
[   20.524680] DiB0070: successfully identified
[   20.524690] dvb-usb: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer.
[   20.527972] DVB: registering new adapter (Hauppauge Nova-TD Stick (52009))
[   20.999385] usb 1-1: DVB: registering adapter 1 frontend 0 (DiBcom 7000PC)...
[   21.589969] DiB0070: successfully identified
[   21.626593] Registered IR keymap rc-dib0700-rc5
[   21.627205] input: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-1/rc/rc0/input5
[   21.627360] rc0: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-1/rc/rc0
[   21.627872] dvb-usb: schedule remote query interval to 50 msecs.
[   21.627880] dvb-usb: Hauppauge Nova-TD Stick (52009) successfully initialized and connected.
[   21.631543] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_dib0700
[   21.715817] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (1029) terminated with status 1
[   21.780130] init: plymouth-splash main process (1038) terminated with status 1
```

My initial guess would be it has something to do with the IR key-map, since i never got any of that on the server that i had running previously. But I’m completely lost with the last two logs, not sure what either of those are but whatever they are they have been terminated...

Hope someone could shine some light onto this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with tvheadend and vlc. 
You probably use wrong plugin HTSP plugin. All that I have tried not showing the plugin in vlc Local Netword submenu exept plugin build #68. The problem with this plugin is that there is no sound on the HD channels because they are using AAC filter.
I downloaded them from [here](https://ci.btbn.de/job/vlc-htsp-plugin/68/)

Comment: Hi there, this isn't the problem as far as i can see, My Pi that i have configured to find the backend server is not changed, all that i have changed is, i made a copy of a physical machine into a virtual machine, all the same IP address's etc. So i doubt its any plugin/software package problem that i have. I believe it's something to do with the virtual machine config, hence the new errors in the Dmesg.

Comment: I mention that in virtual machines (I use Virtualbox - last build) not everything goes as I expected, so I use it only on real Ubuntu 14.04 (I upgraded it to this version). If You have solution for virtual machine, write it here.